# Docker-compose up creates container but coudn't start it

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I need to do manually, in PowerShell, what Visual Studio 2017 does automatically when creating Docker image from my solution (asp.net core web application).

```
docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" -f "docker-compose.override.yml" -f "docker-
compose.vs.release.yml" -p dockercompose32 up --build -d
```

It creates new images(when I'm building from the scratch but it doesn't rebuild old image if something in the project is changed) and `docker ps` shows :

```
CONTAINER ID      COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
3b9b2996cf61   "tail -f /dev/null"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:32812->80/tcp   dockercompose32_some_name
```

But on `http://localhost:32812/api/values/` i get an error `GET http://localhost:32804/api/values/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and if I run container from the same image with `docker run -d -p 4000:80 image_name` it works.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To pull in changes from your images, I would run this as three commands:

```
export COMPOSE_FILE="docker-compose.yml:docker-compose.override.yml:docker-compose.vs.release.yml"
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=dockercompose32
docker-compose pull
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

If the build is showing no changes, then the build command may not be able to see what has changed. You can use `docker-compose build --no-cache` if the changes are coming from something outside of the docker context, which will force the entire image to be rebuilt even if it would normally use the cache.